# How to fix function that helps prepare dishes based on recipes?

Tags: python

I'm trying to execute a function that will prepare a dish as long as the user has enough ingredients in their inventory. However, I'm very unsure on how to go about on creating this function.

So far, I have this:

```
def CanPrepareDish(recipe_name):
    recipe = cookbook.getRecipe(recipe_name)
    for ingred in recipe:
        if ingred not in iinventory:
            return False
        if iinventory[ingred] < recipe[ingred]:
            return False
    return True

def preparedish(recipe_name):
    if not CanPrepareDish(recipe_name):
        print("Not enough ingredients")
    else:
        dish = cookbook.getRecipe(recipe_name)
        recipe = dish.getName()
        for recipe in cookbook.allRecipes():
            iinventory[ingred] -= recipe[ingred]
        if recipe_name == recipe.getName():
            iinventory[recipe_name] += 1
        else:
            iinventory[recipe_name] = 1
            print("Dish prepared")


class Cookbook:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Cooklist=[]
    def addRecipe(self,Recipe):
        self.Cooklist.append(Recipe)
    def getRecipe(self,recipe_name):
        for recipe in self.Cooklist:
            if recipe_name == recipe.getName():
                return recipe
    def allRecipes(self):
        for Recipe in self.Cooklist:
            return self.Cooklist

cookbook=Cookbook()
```

```html
class Iinventory:
    def __init__(self):
        self.apple_num=0
        self.beet_num=0
        self.carrot_num=0
    def getApples(self):
        return int(self.apple_num)
    def getBeets(self):
        return int(self.beet_num)
    def getCarrots(self):
        return int(self.carrot_num)

iinventory=Iinventory()
```

With `CanPrepareDish(recipe_name)` I want to check if there are enough ingredients that allows them to actually prepare the dish, so if they can't `preparedish` will print that they don't have enough ingredients. BUT I can't iterate through the recipe since it's an object so how would I iterate through the recipe to see if there are enough ingredients?

With `preparedish`, I have no idea on how to go along with this. So it is supposed to check if there are enough ingredients with `CanPrepareDish` and if it can, then it goes along with preparing the dish and removing the ingredients used from the `iinventory` (which is also an object).

The Recipe object/class that was created.

```html
class Recipe:
    def __init__(self,name,apple_num,beet_num,carrot_num):
        self.name=str(name)
        self.apple_num=int(apple_num)
        self.beet_num=int(beet_num)
        self.carrot_num=int(carrot_num)
    def getName(self):
        return self.name
    def getApples(self):
        return self.apple_num
    def getBeets(self):
        return self.beet_num
    def getCarrots(self):
        return self.carrot_num
```

Comment: As far as I can tell you haven't shown us what a `recipe` object is, so how can we answer?

Comment: I added the Recipe class that I created, which I believe contains the recipe object?

Comment: Thanks. You can't iterate through the recipe because recipes aren't general, they are defined to be about three special ingredients: apples, beets, and carrots. To get the number of e.g. apples in the recipe, call recipe.getApples().

Answer (score 0):

The original answer is below, this top part is an update to reflect new information.  Firstly, see the code dump below:

```
class Ingredients:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ingredients = {"apples": 0, "beets": 0, "carrots": 0}

    def getApples(self):
        return self.ingredients["apples"]

    def getBeets(self):
        return self.ingredients["beets"]

    def getCarrots(self):
        return self.ingredients["carrots"]


class Iinventory(Ingredients):
    def __init__(self):
        Ingredients.__init__(self)


class Recipe(Ingredients):
    def __init__(self, name, apple_num, beet_num, carrot_num):
        Ingredients.__init__(self)
        self.name = name
        self.ingredients["apples"] = apple_num
        self.ingredients["beets"] = beet_num
        self.ingredients["carrots"] = carrot_num

    def getName(self):
        return self.name


def CanPrepareDish(recipe_name, inventory):
    recipe = cookbook.getRecipe(recipe_name)
    for ingred in recipe.ingredients.keys():
        if ingred not in inventory.ingredients.keys():
            return False
        if inventory.ingredients[ingred] < recipe.ingredients[ingred]:
            return False
    return True


def preparedish(recipe_name, inventory):
    if not CanPrepareDish(recipe_name, inventory):
        print("Not enough ingredients")
    else:
        dish = cookbook.getRecipe(recipe_name)
        recipe = dish.getName()
        for recipe in cookbook.allRecipes():
            inventory[ingred] -= recipe[ingred]
        if recipe_name == recipe.getName():
            inventory[recipe_name] += 1
        else:
            inventory[recipe_name] = 1
            print("Dish prepared")


class Cookbook:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Cooklist = []

    def addRecipe(self, Recipe):
        self.Cooklist.append(Recipe)

    def getRecipe(self, recipe_name):
        for recipe in self.Cooklist:
            if recipe_name == recipe.getName():
                return recipe

    def allRecipes(self):
        for _ in self.Cooklist:
            return self.Cooklist


cookbook = Cookbook()
r = Recipe("food", 1, 2, 3)
cookbook.addRecipe(r)
iinventory = Iinventory()
iinventory.ingredients["apples"] = 5
iinventory.ingredients["beets"] = 5
iinventory.ingredients["carrots"] = 5

print(iinventory.getApples())
print(r.getBeets())

if CanPrepareDish("food", iinventory):
    print("Can make recipe")
else:
    print("Nope")
```

Before I explain the changes, I just want to point out a couple of small issues.  1.  The preparedish function won't work right now, as it uses an *ingred* variable that comes from outside the function - I'm assuming you have that under control though.  2.  the *if ingred not in inventory.ingredients.keys()* part will never be triggered, as currently the way things are structured both the Iinventory and Recipe classes will always have all the ingredients defined in them.

So, to explain the above.  Firstly, I noticed that your Iinventory and Recipe classes duplicated a lot of the same stuff, so I made them both subclasses of a top-level Ingredients class.  In fact, Iinventory as it currently stands is nothing more than Ingredients under a new name.  There's a bit more to Recipe, but basically, it is just setting the same stuff as before.  Strictly speaking you don't actually need to define the all-zeros dictionary at Ingredients' init but I personally feel it is neater.

To do iteration over the different types of ingredients, just call .keys() on 
the ingredients member of each object.

Also, for certain reasons, I made the CanPrepareDish and preparedish functions take the inventory to work with as another parameter.  This just means that I can define those things at the top and then work with them down the bottom, it's entirely up to you whether you keep it that way.

I included some code for testing out the implementation at the bottom.  If you comment out the preparedish() function, you should be able to see it all working.

Is there any part you would like further clarification on?

---

As @Denziloe has pointed out, currently you have three separate variables, and in general, you can't iterate through separate variables.

Based on what you have in CanPrepareDish, I think your best approach would probably be to use a dictionary to store the ingredients.  Note that I can't be certain that this is what you want since I'm not entirely sure what iinventory looks like.

So firstly, change the Recipe class to use a dictionary instead of individual variables:

```
class Recipe:
    def __init__(self, name, apple_num, beet_num, carrot_num):
        self.name = str(name)
        self.ingredientsList = {}
        self.ingredientsList["apples"] = apple_num
        self.ingredientsList["beets"] = beet_num
        self.ingredientsList["carrots"] = carrot_num

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getApples(self):
        return self.ingredientsList["apples"]

    def getBeets(self):
        return self.ingredientsList["beets"]

    def getCarrots(self):
        return self.ingredientsList["carrots"]
```

and then change CanPrepareDish to:

```
def CanPrepareDish(recipe_name):
    recipe = cookbook.getRecipe(recipe_name)
    for ingred in recipe.ingredientsList.keys():
        if ingred not in iinventory:
            return False
        if iinventory[ingred] < recipe.ingredientsList[ingred]:
            return False
    return True
```

The only change to the CanPrepareDish function is changing the for loop to use recipe.ingredientsList.keys().

Give this a try and see if it helps at all.  Otherwise, you'll probably have to edit the question again to show us what iinventory looks like in order for anyone to be able to help further.

Comment: the iinventory is actually a class as well. I will edit my question

Comment: @Kris.  Oh right, I have now updated my answer to reflect the new information.  Hopefully, this helps.